# Регулярное выражение в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Использую Postgres (если это важно). Есть задача найди среди пользователей тех, у кого email содержит в себе определенную строку.

Например есть пользователи со следующими email-ами: **vasya@petya.ru, petya@test.ru, dima@test.ru, petya123@gmail.com, superPetya@rambler.ru**

Строка, по которой происходит поиск - **petya**.
Соотвественно, используя регулярку (наверное?), должны вывестись строки из таблицы пользователей, у которых email-ы **petya@test.ru**, **petya123@gmail.com** и **superPetya@rambler.ru**

**UPD.** Должна быть возможность найти и наоборот. Например при исходной строке **petya123** нужно найти те же email-ы, что указаны выше.

Подскажите как это сделать? Отдельное спасибо будет тому, кто покажет (отдельным примером), как вместо строки petya можно передать целый email (petya@test.ru) и провести поиск по той части, которая до знака @.

Answer (score 2):

Работа для обычного `ILIKE`, разве нет?

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
 WHERE email ILIKE '%petya%'
;
```

Последний ваш параграф не понял, но если вам нужно взять юзернейм из
целого адреса, я рекомендую делать это на стороне приложения.  Если же
никак, то как-то так:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
 WHERE email ILIKE '%' || substring('petya@example.ru' from '^[^@]*') || '%'
;
```

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста то, что пометил только что как UPD. С этим на самом деле и основная загвоздка.

Comment: Ваш новый пункт не понятен.  Как из `petya123` можно получить `superPetya@rambler.ru`?

Comment: Вот и я не знаю. Знал бы не спрашивал)). Что-то типа подстроки в строке или как-то так.

Comment: Такие вещи лучше решать в приложении, особенно когда алгоритм «нечёткого поиска» непонятен и будет изменяться.  Можете почитать про [`substring`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) и [_full text search_](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch.html).